# how to run different SQL based on DB version

Tags: sql, oracle

i need a single query which would run the below query based on the DB version.
To get DB version:

```
select distinct substr(version, 1, 2) version  from product_component_version
```

This gives the version as 11,12 or 19.
If the version is 11 run:

```
select USERNAME,SYSDBA,SYSOPER,SYSASM from v$pwfile_users
```

and if its 12 or 19 run:

```
select USERNAME, SYSDBA, SYSOPER, SYSASM, SYSBACKUP, SYSDG, SYSKM, CON_ID from v$pwfile_users
```

And also there should be no error when it is run on any version of the DB.(just no rows selected)
Please suggest.Thanks.

Comment: You need two separate queries.

Comment: Let me know if you're using sqlplus or sqlcl, in this case I have also another solution by Tanel Poder. You can find it an example here: https://github.com/xtender/xt_scripts/blob/master/param.sql

Comment: Conditional compilation is a good solution for developers, but not for DBAs, since they often have hundreds of different databases and they have no official permission to create own objects in some of them, for example in case of 3rd-party vendor databases. In such case it's better to use simple cross-version queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it's easier to check release version using v$instance:

```sql
select version from v$instance;
```

Newer versions also have `version_full` column:

```sql
SQL> select version,version_full from v$instance;

VERSION           VERSION_FULL
----------------- -----------------
18.0.0.0.0        18.3.0.0.0
```

Then even if your version has no `VERSION_FULL` column, you can use `xmltable` to create a cross-version query that will not fail in case of missing column:

```sql
select nvl(version_full, version) as ver
from xmltable('ora:view("SYS","V_$INSTANCE")/ROW' 
columns 
  x xmltype path '.',
  version      varchar2(30) path 'VERSION',
  version_full varchar2(30) path '*[name() eq "VERSION_FULL"]'
  );
```

Result:

```sql
VER
------------------------------
18.3.0.0.0
```

Then you can do the same with your main query, you don't even need to know exact version, just create a similar query that ignores missing columns:

```sql
select *
from xmltable('ora:view("SYS","V_$pwfile_users")/ROW' 
columns 
   USERNAME       varchar2(30) path 'USERNAME'
  ,SYSDBA         varchar2(5)  path 'SYSDBA '
  ,SYSOPER        varchar2(5)  path 'SYSOPER'
  ,SYSASM         varchar2(5)  path 'SYSASM '
  ,SYSBACKUP      varchar2(5)  path '*[name() eq "SYSBACKUP"]'
  ,SYSDG          varchar2(5)  path '*[name() eq "SYSDG"]'
  ,SYSKM          varchar2(5)  path '*[name() eq "SYSKM"]'
  ,ACCOUNT_STATUS varchar2(5)  path '*[name() eq "ACCOUNT_STATUS"]'
  ,CON_ID         int          path '*[name() eq "CON_ID"]'
  ,COMMON         varchar2(3)  path '*[name() eq "COMMON"]'
  );
```

Results:

```
USERNAME                       SYSDB SYSOP SYSAS SYSBA SYSDG SYSKM ACCOU     CON_ID COM
------------------------------ ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ---------- ---
SYS                            TRUE  TRUE  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE OPEN           0 YES
SYSDG                          FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE OPEN           0 YES
SYSBACKUP                      FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  FALSE FALSE OPEN           0 YES
SYSKM                          FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE  OPEN           0 YES
```

Example results from 11.2:

```
USERNAME SYSDB SYSOPER SYSASM SYSBA SYSDG SYSKM ACCOUNT_STAT     CON_ID COMMON
-------- ----- ------- ------ ----- ----- ----- ------------ ---------- -------
SYS      TRUE  TRUE    FALSE
```

Comment: @vivek I haven't understood your problem: you can use this query and specify all the columns `USERNAME,SYSDBA,SYSOPER,SYSASM,SYSBACKUP,SYSDG,SYSKM,ACCOUNT_STATUS,CON_ID,COMMON`

Comment: @vivek Try this query on 11g and you will see all the columns, but there will be NULLs in the columns which do not exist in 11g

Comment: I've added an example for results from 11.2

Comment: just created the metric in OEM and it works fine,leaving the columns not available in that version empty.This should suffice the requirement most probably.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ok, great, so please mark the answer as a correct one if it works for you

Answer (score 3):

What about creating PROCEDURE and inside this PROCEDURE you can set the query to be run depends on the version

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE My_CODE AS

$IF DBMS_DB_VERSION.VER_LE_11 $THEN
 select ...... 
$ELSE
 Select ....  
$END
```

Comment: DBMS_DB_VERSION.VER_LE_11 is not present in older versions, you have to use DBMS_DB_VERSION.VERSION...

Comment: Thank you, i am just showing him the idea or concept  here

Answer (score 1):

One way that might get as close to your task as it gets might be to create a package function and use that to get the data:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE xxx3 IS 
  TYPE rec IS RECORD (
  USERNAME                       VARCHAR2(30 BYTE),
  SYSDBA                         VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  SYSOPER                        VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  SYSASM                         VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  SYSBACKUP                      VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  SYSDG                          VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  SYSKM                          VARCHAR2(5 BYTE),
  CON_ID                         NUMBER);
  
  TYPE tab IS TABLE OF REC;
  
  FUNCTION getPWFile_USERS RETURN tab PIPELINED;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY xxx3 IS 
  FUNCTION getPWFile_USERS 
    RETURN tab PIPELINED 
  IS
    l_erg tab;
  BEGIN
    $IF DBMS_DB_VERSION.VERSION > 10 $THEN
    FOR c IN (SELECT listagg(NVL(column_name, 'NULL'),',') within GROUP (ORDER BY lvl) cols
                FROM (SELECT LEVEL lvl FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 9) l 
                LEFT join dba_tab_cols c
                  ON c.owner = 'SYS'
                 AND c.table_name = 'V_$PWFILE_USERS'
                 AND c.column_id = l.lvl)
    LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT '||c.cols||' FROM SYS.V_$PWFILE_USERS'
      BULK COLLECT INTO l_erg;
        
      IF l_erg.COUNT > 0 THEN
        FOR i IN 1..l_erg.COUNT LOOP
          PIPE ROW (l_erg(i));
        END LOOP;
      END IF;
    END LOOP;
    $END
    RETURN;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_NEEDED THEN NULL;
  END;
END;
```

And then use the following query to SELECT the data:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TABLE(xxx3.getPWFile_USERS)
```

Answer (score 0):

use the CASE WHEN option

```
SELECT...
CASE WHEN ....
THEN
FROM...
```

Comment: It would fail during parsing since there is no such columns in some versions